# Why won't my caesar shift work properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code:

```
text = input("What's your text:  ")
shift = int(input("What's your shift: "))

def caesar_shift(text, shift):
    cipher = ""
    for i in text:
        if i.isalpha():
            stayIn = ord(i) + shift
            if stayIn > ord('z'):
                stayIn -= 26
            lastLetter = chr(stayIn)
        cipher += lastLetter

        print("Your ciphertext is: ", cipher)

    return cipher

caesar_shift(text, shift)
```

When I run it, and for example, the test is hello world, and the shift is 1, I get:

```
What's your text:  hello world
What's your shift: 1
Your ciphertext is:  i
Your ciphertext is:  if
Your ciphertext is:  ifm
Your ciphertext is:  ifmm
Your ciphertext is:  ifmmp
Your ciphertext is:  ifmmpp
Your ciphertext is:  ifmmppx
Your ciphertext is:  ifmmppxp
Your ciphertext is:  ifmmppxps
Your ciphertext is:  ifmmppxpsm
Your ciphertext is:  ifmmppxpsme
```

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You do

```
if i.isalpha():
```

but you have no else-clause for that if. That means that you add the last letter also when it is not a letter. Hence `ifmmpp` instead of `ifmmp` for `hello`.

That bit should be changed to:

```
if i.isalpha():
    stayIn = ord(i) + shift
    if stayIn > ord('z'):
        stayIn -= 26
    lastLetter = chr(stayIn)
    cipher += lastLetter
else:
    cipher += i
```

If you don't want the result to be printed out once for every loop, move it outside the loop.

Comment: No the answer is right, i'm wondering why it prints it out like that, how do I get the last answer?

Comment: @Samir: No, the answer is incorrect, which you will notice if you shift it back. I updated the explanation to cover your other question as well.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the print problem, you have:

```
def caesar_shift(text, shift):
    cipher = ""
    for i in text:
        ...

        print("Your ciphertext is: ", cipher)

    return cipher

caesar_shift(text, shift)
```

But you should have

```
def caesar_shift(text, shift):
    cipher = ""
    for i in text:
        ...

    print("Your ciphertext is: ", cipher)

    return cipher

caesar_shift(text, shift)
```

Or better yet

```
def caesar_shift(text, shift):
    cipher = ""
    for i in text:
        ...

    return cipher

print("Your ciphertext is: ", caesar_shift(text, shift))
```